# Women doctors wearing pants scrubs - tzniut

Tags: tznius-modesty

This question begins with two assumptions - assuming there is no issue of beged isha and assuming that pants are immodest (which is the position of many orthodox women).

Is there a reason why this would be permitted?

It was suggested that the issue of pants is dat yehudit, which would depend on what how women usually dress. Perhaps in this setting, modest women did not accept this upon themselves.

On the other hand, perhaps pants are inherently immodest, irrespective of what women do. If this is the case, perhaps wide pants would be different.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to provide a reason to prohibit (ignoring beged isha) before asking if it's permitted? What is immodest about scrubs?

Comment: see here: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2008/08/would-rashi-necessarily-condemn-pants.html

Comment: I dont understand the question 'Scrubs are designed to be simple (with minimal places for contaminants to hide),  etc.' It seems this is the only safe way to be a doctor. I am sure pikuach nefesh over rides any tzniut issur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can pants ever be considered modest?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94187/can-pants-ever-be-considered-modest)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The question is not whether or nor pants are modest, I thought that was clear, but I guess not clear enough. I edited the question .

Comment: All of the female doctors and nurses I know have taken the material used to make medical outerwear and fashioned skirts out of them to wear over their medical pants. Barring such a possibility, consider that doctors’ garb isn’t just for show; it’s specially designed to prevent germs from festering on them as much as possible. Surely the potential threat of carrying around such pathogens around already sick patients should outweigh tznius?

Comment: @DonielF Thank you for mentioning that, בזכות נשים צדקניות... but  I've seen frum women wear the pants scrubs as well. As far as the pikuach nefesh argument, I certainly hear that consideration but that would put us into the argument of whether or not women should put themselves into that position. But since there is a a solution, as you mention, there's no need to get into that.

Comment: @Mark I see how that discussion of if they can לכתחילה put themselves in that situation is any different than the same argument about [Kohanim becoming doctors](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33937/) with טומאת מת concerns.

Comment: @DonielF Thank you. I wish I could find something concrete on this issue. But thank you for the advice of fashioning a skirt, I will pass that on.